# Best way to set up model and database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rails-activerecord, models

I am creating an app that deals with sports teams. Currently I have two models. A Users.rb model and a Teams.rb model. Within the users of the app I would like to have team captains and teammates. I would like to give the captain the privledge of creating the team when they sign up. I would like the a captain to belong to a team and teammates belong to a team. I would like the team to just have one captain. What would the best way to set this up? Should I have a captain and a teammate alias in the users model? Or would it be better to make a captains.rb model?

Comment: Do captains and teammates have some different attributes?

Comment: **Just a warning: Rails' convention is to use singular nouns for models. `rails g model Users` would give you:** [WARNING] The model name 'Users' was recognized as a plural, using the singular 'User' instead. Override with --force-plural or setup custom inflection rules for this noun before running the generator.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, First lets lay out the relationship assumptions since there are some that are vague from your descriptions:

A user can:

- Be many captains
- Be on many teams

A team can:

- Belong to one captain
- Have many users as teammates

From this I think you need 3 models:

- User
- Team
- Teammates that acts as the has_many_through join table between users and teams

The Teammate model would definitely have:

- user_id
- team_id
- Possible role/type field

And this leaves the point where you have to make a decision about the app based on how you will use the data. Since a team will only have one captain you could leave out the role field in the teammate model and just add a user_id or captain_id to the actual Team model. This would mean captain is treated as special and different from the other team mates always. However, I'm guessing for somethings you could want to loop through all members of the team including the captain. That's why you should probably just make captain a special role on the teammate model and add validation to make sure there is only one captain. Then you don't have to do special handling for the captain whenever looping through the entire team.

Assuming you go with the role field then your final models would have the following relations:

Teammate

- belongs_to :team
- belongs_to :user

User

- has_many :teammates
- has_many :teams, through: :teammates

Team

- has_many :teammates
- has_many :users, through: :teammates
- has_one :team_captain,  -> { where role: 'captain' }, class_name: 'Teammate'

You could also get fancier with that last one by working out a has_many through to get to the captain user instead of the captain team_mate. This post has some interesting details on advanced has_one:

http://www.rojotek.com/blog/2014/05/16/cool-stuff-you-can-do-with-rails-has_one/

Answer (score 0):

If the captains and teammates have different attributes so i think its better to separate the models but if this is not the case so why do not you create a join table for teammates between users and team and the team model has an owner id.

Schema example :

Team ( owner_id, .....)

Teammates( user_id, team_id, .... )

This will help you to set a belongs_to association between Team and User models as Captain using the owner_id column in the team model and the other members can be done by has_many teammates through Teammates Model or even use has_and_belongs_to_many association.
By this way you will manage to let one user has_one team or even a teammate within other teams.

Another idea to let all the members within the join table with an extra Column to decide its role within the team ,which will give you more control if you are going to add more roles in the future, and define your validations and scoops to serve that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do as follow:

At the beginning app allows you to signup as "user aka team owner" or as "teammate"

1. Users.rb - can create teams and invite other teammates. Has administrative rights.
2. Teams.rb - belongs to User and has many Teammates.
3. Teammates.rb - belongs to Teams.
4. All assigned teammates could have admin-visible checkbox "captain" with boolean value. This could save you from creating one more db table. Unless "captain" is "true", teammate status is "simple player". Otherwise it's "captain".

Other way is to allow Users to create Teams and Teammates.

1. User would has_many Teams and Teammates.
2. Teammate belongs_to User and belongs_to the Team.
3. Team belongs_to User and has_many Teammates.